# How to keep admin login when use ajaxProcess?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

Module send only Ajax process to module controller every 5 seconds. After few minutes prestashop automatically logged out employee. How I can keep stay loggin?

Comment: Tag your question with the relevant Prestashop version.

Answer (score 1):

In your ajaxProcess function, do this:

```
$cookie = Context::getContext()->cookie;
$cookie->write();
```

This will refresh the duration of your admin cookie when your ajaxProcess returns, that is when the headers are sent which is how cookies get set.

Optionally you can include this code above the write() call so that the last activity time is also recorded

```
if (!Tools::getValue('stay_logged_in')) {
   $cookie->last_activity = time();
}
```

You can see this code in action in `/controllers/admin/AdminLoginController.php`